# How to dynamically change CSS/highlight button elements based on filtered data in React JS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, button

I have a UI consisting of a large number of buttons (over 300) that are styled according to a CSS stylesheet.

How would I highlight some of these buttons based on data that is passed down.

For example, here are some of the buttons I have. They all have a unique value assigned to them that allows the user to pull up more information when clicked (hence the onClick).

```
<div className="btn">
   <button type = "button" name = "channelID" value = 'A01' onClick = {this.onClick}>A01</button>
   <button type = "button" name = "channelID" value = 'A02' onClick = {this.onClick}>A02</button>
   <button type = "button" name = "channelID" value = 'A03' onClick = {this.onClick}>A03</button>
   <button type = "button" name = "channelID" value = 'A04' onClick = {this.onClick}>A04</button>
   <button type = "button" name = "channelID" value = 'A05' onClick = {this.onClick}>A05</button>
</div>
```

By default, let's say the CSS stylesheet styles the buttons like this:

```
.btn button = {
   background-color: black;
   color: white
}
```

I also have a select tag which should allow the user to select a particular property of the channels:

```
<select name="datatype" onChange={this.handleChange}>
   <option>--- Data Type ---</option>
   <option value="inspected">View Inspected Channels</option>
   <option value="requiresReplacement">View Channels to Replace</option>
</select>
```

Let's say someone selects "Inspected" from this dropdown.
It would filter and return only the channels that have the inspected property set to true from the main data. It would look something like this where only channels A02, A03, and A05 have been inspected:

```
state = { 
   channelsToHighlight = [
      { 
         channelID: "A02",
         inspected: true
      }, 
      { 
         channelID: "A03",
         inspected: true
      }, 
      { 
         channelID: "A05",
         inspected: true
      }, 
   ]
}
```

(If the user had selected the "View Channels to Replace" option, it would pull up a different subset of channels.)

I would now like the channels A02, A03 and A05 to have a different background color so they appear highlighted.

I've considered adding a getStyle() option to my component which would render conditionally but I'm not exactly sure how I would do this. Is it possible to match the channelID property from the channelsToHighlight object to the values I've set to each button?

Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Comment: you can have another css class e.g. `.selected-btn` which has the css properties you require (i.e. a different colour background),  you can use the current state, to determine whether to set className on your buttons to include the selected-btn class

Comment: assuming the state is in the same component as your buttons, this could be determined by: `this.state.channelsToHighlight.find(c => c.channelID == "A02").inspected` - for "A02"

Comment: How are you rendering the buttons? Is it via a loop `map`, `forEach`, `filter`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your button are rendered in a `map()` function, I would recommend you make a `<Button />` component which will receive as props the item of the state relevant to it. Then you can easily do one of the following.
Inline styles:

```
<button style={{ backgroundColor: state.channelsToHighlight.inspected ? 'black' : 'white' }}></button>
```

Or you can toggle a CSS class based on state:

```
<button className={state.channelsToHighlight.inspected ? 'selected' : 'unselected'}></button>
```

If you're typing all your buttons manually, unless you have a good reason for it, maybe you should consider iterating over the array and render using a `map` function in JSX.

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: This wont work as `this.state.channelsToHighlight` is an array, you would need to do it more like this: `this.state.channelsToHighlight.find(c => c.channelID == "A02").inspected`  and change the channel id for each button - you will also get errors if the find fails to find the channel in channelsToHighlight,  so would either have to have them in the state as false, or add additional logic

Comment: use: 
`this.state.channelsToHighlight.find(c => c.channelID == "A02")?.inspected`

Comment: Thanks! for some reason I was assuming he is rendering the elements in a `map` func... Then it's easy to get and use the state of each button. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

First add CSS for the style you want selected buttons to have:

```
.selected-button = {
   background-color: yellow;
   color: black
}
```

Then in your render, dip into your state (assuming state is in same components, else dip into props) to get the current value of `inspected` for this button, and if inspected is true, add `selected-button` class to specific button.

```
<div className="btn">
   <button className={this.state.channelsToHighlight.find(c => c.channelID == "A01")?.inspected ? "selected-button" : ""} type = "button" name = "channelID" value = 'A01' onClick = {this.onClick}>A01</button>
   <button className={this.state.channelsToHighlight.find(c => c.channelID == "A02")?.inspected ? "selected-button" : ""} type = "button" name = "channelID" value = 'A02' onClick = {this.onClick}>A02</button>
   <button className={this.state.channelsToHighlight.find(c => c.channelID == "A03")?.inspected ? "selected-button" : ""} type = "button" name = "channelID" value = 'A03' onClick = {this.onClick}>A03</button>
   <button className={this.state.channelsToHighlight.find(c => c.channelID == "A04")?.inspected ? "selected-button" : ""} type = "button" name = "channelID" value = 'A04' onClick = {this.onClick}>A04</button>
   <button className={this.state.channelsToHighlight.find(c => c.channelID == "A05")?.inspected ? "selected-button" : ""} type = "button" name = "channelID" value = 'A05' onClick = {this.onClick}>A05</button>
</div>
```

Side note: Your button generation follows the same pattern for each button, with just the value and text changing.  you could clean this up using the map function. It is not clear if this is just a sample - or actually code from your project, but here is a sample of how to do this with the code you posted.  This will also massively improve performance, as the `find` calls are removed, and the finds, if you have a lot of buttons, would be slow.  Using the map resolves this.

First refactor your state to have an entry per button.

```
state = { 
   channels = [
      { 
         channelID: "A01",
         inspected: false
      }, 
      { 
         channelID: "A02",
         inspected: true
      }, 
      { 
         channelID: "A03",
         inspected: true
      }, 
      { 
         channelID: "A04",
         inspected: false
      }, 
      { 
         channelID: "A05",
         inspected: true
      }, 
   ]
}
```

Then change your render to use map

```
<div className="btn">
  { 
      this.state.channels.map(ch => <button className={ch.inspected ? "selected-button" : ""} type = "button" name = "channelID" value = {ch.channelID} onClick = {this.onClick}>{ch.channelID}</button>)
  }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check this example. hope it helps you.

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

export default class HighlightButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            color: "primary",
            channels: [
                {channelID: "A01", inspected: false},
                {channelID: "A02", inspected: true},
                {channelID: "A03", inspected: true},
                {channelID: "A04", inspected: false},
                {channelID: "A05", inspected: true},
            ],
            channelsToHighlight: [],
            channelsToNonHighlight: []
        }
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        let value = event.target.value;
        this.setState(prevState => {
            let chans = prevState.channels.filter(ch => ch.inspected === (value === "inspected"));
            return {channelsToHighlight: chans}
        })
        this.setState(prevState => {
            let chans = prevState.channels.filter(ch => ch.inspected === (value === "requiresReplacement"));
            return {channelsToNonHighlight: chans}
        })
    };
    onClick = () => {

    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <select name="datatype" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                    <option>--- Data Type ---</option>
                    <option value="inspected">View Inspected Channels</option>
                    <option value="requiresReplacement">View Channels to Replace</option>
                </select>
                <div className="btn">
                    {
                        this.state.channelsToHighlight.map((channel, index) =>
                            <Button key={index} name={channel.channelID} value={channel.channelID}
                                    onClick={this.onClick} variant="contained"
                                    color={channel.inspected ? "primary" : "secondary"}>{channel.channelID}</Button>
                        )
                    }
                    {
                        this.state.channelsToNonHighlight.map((channel, index) =>
                            <Button key={index} name={channel.channelID} value={channel.channelID}
                                    onClick={this.onClick} variant="contained"
                                    color={channel.inspected ? "primary" : "secondary"}>{channel.channelID}</Button>
                        )
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```